# Android - Cannot resolve method 'onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)

Tags: java, android

I need to set/add a photo/movie as an attachment to ToDo App.
Unfortunately the word: onActivityResult in line super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); is highlighted in red and i'm getting an error:

"Cannot resolve method 'onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)' "

AddActivity.java

```
    Button button_z = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_z);
        button_z.setonclickListener(new View.onclickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onclick(View view2) {

                    selectImage();
 }
           @Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

                  Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                           90, bytes);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
                            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                            FileOutputStream fo;
                            try {
                                destination.createNewFile();
                                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                                fo.close();
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {

                            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
                            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(AddActivity.this, selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
                            Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
                            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                            cursor.moveToFirst();
                            String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                            Bitmap bm;
                            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
                            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
                            int scale = 1;

                            while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                                    && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                                scale *= 2;
                            options.inSampleSize = scale;
                            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        }
                    }

        private void selectImage() {
            final CharSequence[] items = { "Zrób zdjęcie lub nagranie", "Wybierz istniejące", "Anuluj" };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Dodaj załącznik");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.onclickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onclick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (items[item].equals("Zrób zdjęcie lub nagranie")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                    } else if (items[item].equals("Wybierz istniejące")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        startActivityForResult(
                                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Wybierz plik"),
                                SELECT_FILE);
                    } else if (items[item].equals("Anuluj")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `);` in your code.

```
Button button_z = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_z);
button_z.setonclickListener(new View.onclickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onclick(View view2) {

        selectImage();
    }
});  //here
```